# Python decorators implementation

Tags: python

I am trying to understand python decorators so I decided to check the inner workings of django ***@login_required*** decorator. After looking at the source code, I got here:

```
def user_passes_test(test_func, login_url=None, 
    redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user passes the given test,
    redirecting to the log-in page if necessary. The test should be a callable
    that takes the user object and returns True if the user passes.
    """
```

From what I understand, the above function is supposed to use the return value of **test_func** to determine whether to redirect user to login page or allow user to continue. My problem is that i can't find anywhere this **test_func** is called. How does the above function **user_passes_test** work exactly. Any help will be appreciated.

***edit:***

I have realized that I am the problem since I was looking at the source code on django documentation and I have just noticed that there is an indentation error. Am all good now.

Comment: Is this the full code of that decorator?

Answer (score 3):

It's called [in this line](https://github.com/django/django/blob/afc06b56256f78ab832ff8066ac6f34b7443de22/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py#L20).

To explain what's going on, let's use a simpler example. Assume you have various functions (corresponding to the views) that need to have their arguments checked (corresponding to the user check) before being executed; if the arguments fail the check, the result should be `None` (corresponding to the login redirect).

Here's example code, the structure of which matches Django's `user_passes_test`:

```
def arguments_pass_test(test_func):
    def decorator(func):
        def _wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
            if test_func(*args, **kwargs):
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return None
        return _wrapped_func
    return decorator

@arguments_pass_test(lambda x: x != 0)
def inverse(x):
    return 1.0 / x

print(inverse(2)) # 0.5
print(inverse(0)) # None
```

So let's look at how the decorator magic happens, that is this part:

```
@arguments_pass_test(lambda x: x != 0)
def inverse(x):
    return 1.0 / x
```

First off, `arguments_pass_test(lambda x: x != 0)` is just a function call; the `@` doesn't come into play yet. The return value from that function call to `arguments_pass_test` is the inner function called `decorator`, and the naming makes it clear that *this* function is the *actual* decorator.

So now we have this:

```
@decorator
def inverse(x):
    return 1.0 / x
```

The decorator syntax gets translated by Python into something roughly equivalent to this:

```
def inverse(x):
    return 1.0 / x

inverse = decorator(inverse)
```

So `inverse` gets replaced with the the result of calling the `decorator` with the original function `inverse` as its argument `func`. The result of calling the decorator is what's called `_wrapped_func`. So what's happening is similar to this:

```
def _original_inverse(x):
    return 1.0 / x

def _wrapped_func(x):
    if test_func(x): # this doesn't exist here, but bear with me
        return _original_inverse(x)
    else
        return None

inverse = _wrapped_func
```

which is finally equivalent(ish) to

```
def inverse(x):
    if x != 0:
        return 1.0 / x
    else
        return None
```

which is exactly what we were going for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you got that function, but I just freshly install `django` through `pip` on my Python 3.6, and here is what I found in `django.contrib.auth.decorators`. The following is accessible [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.11/_modules/django/contrib/auth/decorators/) as well.

```
def user_passes_test(test_func, login_url=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user passes the given test,
    redirecting to the log-in page if necessary. The test should be a callable
    that takes the user object and returns True if the user passes.
    """

    def decorator(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if test_func(request.user):
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            path = request.build_absolute_uri()
            resolved_login_url = resolve_url(login_url or settings.LOGIN_URL)
            # If the login url is the same scheme and net location then just
            # use the path as the "next" url.
            login_scheme, login_netloc = urlparse(resolved_login_url)[:2]
            current_scheme, current_netloc = urlparse(path)[:2]
            if ((not login_scheme or login_scheme == current_scheme) and
                    (not login_netloc or login_netloc == current_netloc)):
                path = request.get_full_path()
            from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login
            return redirect_to_login(
                path, resolved_login_url, redirect_field_name)
        return _wrapped_view
    return decorator
```

This makes much more sense, since `test_func` is effectively called inside of the decorator.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was looking at the source code on django documentation and I have just noticed that there is an indentation error. Am all good now.